# "Minim Semi-Quaver" Semi Quaver with a space in the note

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music

Hi today I have received audition music for a band for next year but I have a question about some of the notes in the music. They looks like semi-quavers (16th notes) but they have a space in the middle of them like a minim (Half note). Here is an image of it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZvRc.jpg

Can you please tell me what these are?

Comment: Check out http://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm for all your notation questions.

Answer (score 1):

Those are tremolos. You oscillate between the two beamed notes as fast as the beams tell you for the duration of the notehead. In effect the passage you photographed will sound like constant 16th notes (semi-quavers) that last the duration of a half note (minim).

Comment: Actually the correct term is "tremolo", not "trill". A "trill" is something different and unrelated.